# How to get a list of removable (GPT) disks using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get only those disks that are removable.

Using `Get-Disk` doesn't retrieve such `IsRemovable` or `DriveType` to filter out.

**NOTICE:** I have tried the methods in the answers below, but it doesn't work with thumb drives that are formatted as GPT and have more than 1 partition.

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk
```

Would do the trick.

If the value `DriveType` is set to `2`, the disk is a removable disk.

You can find all the details to the `Win32_LogicalDisk WMI Class` in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisk).

Comment: I'm getting some confusing results. None of my drives is removable (none is DriveType=2) and that's not true :( I have a thumb-drive connected to it

Comment: Sorry, my comment was mistaken. My thumb drive has a GPT partition layout and it seems it's not detected as removable. How do I deal with this situation?

Comment: I sadly can't reproduce this behavior on my system

Comment: Get some spare thumb drive and format it using GPT. Create 2 partitions and you're done. This is the kind of drive I want to detect :) I don't know why Windows stops identifying it as removable, when it its a thumb drive. Maybe because the GPT partition table instead of MBR?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Get-Volume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume) Cmdlet:

```
Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'removable'}
```

**EDIT**

Below the powershell code that narrows it down to the physical 'disks' that are removable on the machine:

```
Get-Volume  | Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 'removable'} | Get-Partition | Get-Disk | Select-Object -Unique
```

What troubles me though is that you stated that the 'removable' drive type is not detected in your situation. Might that be something particular to the phone device you are working with? This code works fine on my machine with a GPT thumb drive containing two partitions. See my screenshot where I left out the final selection for unique disk objects:

[image]

Comment: Please, check the OP. I've added a NOTICE part to point out an issue this has.

Comment: GPT. Mmm, interesting. Is there a particular reason for using GPT on a thumb drive?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly my need, but it's how my phone is detected when it's in Mass Storage Mode. I'm creating an application (a deployer) that should detect my phone's drive correctly before doing anything else. If you're curious, it's this application: https://github.com/WoA-project/WoA-Installer/blob/master/Docs/Lumia.md

Comment: I'm doing a silly check now "get the first disk what contains partitions named X and Y of types a and b" (that are particular to the phone), but this check is quite weak.

Comment: Well, it took some patience to change a thumb drive to GPT. I have one and I created two partitions on it. But on my machine `Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 'removable'}` returns both GPT partitions that are on my thumbdrive. Or do you want to drill it down to the physical disk level, what in this case should narrow it down to one?

Comment: I have code that narrows it down to the physical disk. I will edit my answer shortly.